# Python: While using the requests library and an API, how do I change the header "Content-Type" to JSON?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, xml, python-requests

I've been trying to use an api on a website for awhile now and the responses from the api return the data in xml. I want the response to be in JSON format, but when I try adding a header into the http request, it keeps sending the response in xml.

I've tried the following code:

```
import requests

param_list = {'key1': 'value1'}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
url = 'api url'

response = requests.get(url=url, params=param_list, headers=headers,)

print(response.text)
print(response.headers)
```

The second print statement shows that the 'Content-Type' header returns "text/html"

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: `Content-Type` is a response header, setting that in your request is unlikely to achieve anything. Try setting the `Accept` header to `application/json` instead: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept

Comment: Also keep in mind that it's only a suggestion to the server to return JSON. It has no direct correspondence to the response Content-Type - the server may still respond with `text/html` if they want to.

Comment: I tried that before and the two responses I get are:

1) The resource cannot be displayed because the file extension is not being accepted by your browser.

2) The same as before: headers with the "Content-Type" being text/html

Comment: If the api you're working with is only returning xml you'll have to conform to that structure. You could fetch the data as xml and parse it into json

Comment: I was thinking of doing that. I came across the xmltodict library. Would you recommend this one?

Comment: I haven't worked with that library so I cant say if it will suit your needs or not but it doesnt hurt to try it out on some dummy data!